# UITabbarcontroller in IOS5 throws UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency exception

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, ios5

I have the following code for the UITabbarcontroller:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

FirstViewController *firstview = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
[tabBarControllerViews addObject:firstview];
[firstview release];

 SecondViewController *secondview = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[tabBarControllerViews addObject:secondview];
[secondview release];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:arr animated:YES];
[arr release];

self.view = tabBarController.view;
```

This code runs fine on IOS4. I tried it on IOS5 beta and get the following error when tapping on a UITabbarItem:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency',
reason: 'child view controller:<FirstViewController: 0x6e03be0> should have parent view
controller:<MainViewController: 0x6816d20> but actual parent is:<UITabBarController: 0x6b0c110>'
```

Answer (score 23):

replace:

```
self.view = tabBarController.view;
```

with:

```
[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

This will also be backwards compatible with IOS3&4.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same pattern (and problem) in my code. Joe's solution didn't work for me. Looking at the snippet, I'm guessing that you derive a class from UIViewController to allow you to customize something.

The thing to do here, and it is quite simple, is to derive from UITabBarController rather than UIViewController, don't create tabBarController, and anywhere you reference tabBarController, substitute self.

5 minutes and you're no longer throwing the inconsistency exception and you remain backwards compatible with iOS 4. You can still do all of your customization in your derived class (monkeying with the nav controller, etc).

If you have built a complex derivation of UIViewController you need to use, this could be more work.

One small gotcha - if you override LoadView, you'll find that it gets called during the init for the UITabBarController. Makes it hard to set members prior to LoadView, so you may need to split up your initialization.

Good luck!

Comment: The problem with replacing self.view = tabBarController.view;
with self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view as suggested below is that you still have the same inconsistency in your view controller hierarchy, you've taken the view from one view controller and inserted it into a different view controller. If Apple tightens the checking for these cases, this code will fail at some point in the future. Check out the session 102 video from WWDC 2011 on iTunes U for more information.

Comment: Completely agree with Matt. Subclassing from UITabBarController instead of UIViewController did help in solving the issue and also maintaining backward compatibility.

Comment: @interface SettingsViewController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

Comment: I'm in the middle of solving this same problem...  I'm not done, but it looks like this is probably the right way to think about it.  However, I can see why I'm confused...  The docs for UITabBarController say - right in the Quick Help:

"**This class is not intended for subclassing.** Instead, you use instances of it as-is to present an interface that allows the user to choose between different modes of operation."

Are the docs out of date? I'm trying to refresh an app I wrote and haven't touched for a year, and I'm guessing that's why I didn't subclass it in the first place.

Comment: yeah, in fact, this did not work for me.  Perhaps I'm doing it wrong, and when I dig more deeply I'll find out this was really the right way to go - but the docs say don't do it, and the other way worked without changing anything else in my own code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot push or present a UITabbarViewController. Is your First View Controller a UITabBarController ?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem.

When you create a new Master-Detail Application(without story board), you can see this codes below from AppDelegate.m.

```
 MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

"BE NOT DEPENDENT ON MainWindow"
Just start from your own ViewController and set it to delegate.
And don't forget to unlink view from MainWindow.xib else the view will called 2 times.