# Why is it incorrect to insert the view from one view controller into another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

In an iPad application I have a tab Controller containing several view controllers. One of these view Controller (call it MainViewController) needs 2 table views side by side.

So I wrote 2 UITableViewController subclasses and from MainViewController, I alloc/init both subclasses of UITableViewController, and add the tableview from each to the MainViewController's view.

This means that UITableViewController subclasses's views are subviews of MainViewController's view.

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7684648/191463 says that doing that is incorrect and it seems Apple are starting to cut down on it.

I really do not want to have to put all the code from both UITableViewControllers in MainViewController, as it will make it much harder to read and in future could create duplicate code, if I want to use one of the tableview elsewhere in the app by itself.

Is this actually a problem, if it is how do I do it properly?

Comment: Watch the *Implementing UIViewController Containment* video from [WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/).

Answer (score 0):

Apple isn't cutting down on it. This is the only way to create custom container view controllers prior to iOS 5. Apple actually listened to the developers and made it easier to do this sort of thing in iOS 5 with child and parent view controller methods, not to mention they made it so it worked hierarchically.

In most cases, this wouldn't actually be a problem in terms of applications crashing or performance or anything. It can be a problem in some cases, because let's say you have a child view controller. You add the view controller's view to your root view controller. Prior to iOS 5, child view controllers were things like navigation controller view controllers, tab bar controller view controllers, and modal view controllers. What happens when you have a button that calls `[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`? Technically, the view controller isn't being presented as a modal view controller, you added the view to the root view controller view.

In iOS5, you're able to add child view controllers to view controllers and are able to transition from one child view controller to another.

Now even if your view controller doesn't have a different parent, adding a "root" view controller to another root view controller isn't the best way to do it (especially since you don't get access to the parent view controller unless you explicitly create a parentViewController pointer in the child view controller). So in the end, Apple just made it easier and more decoupled.

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to do it so long you take the responsibility of managing the viewController life cycle events

```
initWithNibName...
loadView:
viewDidLoad:...
.
.
viewDidUnload..
dealloc
memoryWarnings
orientation changes
```

So if you create a custom "container view controller" it becomes your responsibility to call all these methods on child viewControllers at the appropriate time. Think of it as "If you were to implement UITabBarController" what all will you have to manage regarding the children ??"

It quickly gets complex. Adding another viewController's view as subview is childs play.

iOS 5 does some of this stuff for you by specifying parent child relationship, however I still haven't seen any sample code anywhere yet to point to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it is not incorrect or wrong to create view controller containers, especially when Apple engineers do that themselves. UITabBarController, UINavigationController or UISplitViewController - they are all view controller containers. More over many great apps with unique UX do that more common than you think. However the real issue is that it's quite hard to do it the right way, so e.g. view lifecycle, memory management and rotation handling is done properly along the hierarchy of views. Fortunately Apple guys did a decent job and iOS5 introduced lots of functionalities regarding controller containers:

- [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

If you're interested how above problems had to be addressed before iOS5, read these two very good blog posts:

- [Writing high-quality view controller containers](http://subjective-objective-c.blogspot.com/2011/08/writing-high-quality-view-controller.html)
- [Using view controllers wisely](http://subjective-objective-c.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-view-controllers-wisely.html)